# Does AWS SNS / SnsClient support sending SMS Messages with UTF8 characters?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, utf-8, sms, amazon-sns

I have the following simple code to send an SMS message according to an incoming api request, but the message arrives at the phone with the accents replaced by their corresponding ascii versions.

Does AWS SNS support sending messages like "You won the áéíóúñ product" so they that arrive properly?

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
  public function send(Request $request){    
    $to = $request->input('phone');
    $message = $request->input('message');

    $client = new SnsClient([
      'version' => '2010-03-31',
      'credentials' => new Credentials(
          env('SMS_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
          env('SMS_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
      ),
      'region' => env('SMS_AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    ]);

    $client->SetSMSAttributes([
      'attributes' => [
          'DefaultSMSType' => 'Transactional',
      ]
    ]);

    $client->publish([
      'Message' => $message,
      'PhoneNumber' => $to,
    ]);

    return [$to, $message];
  }
}
```

The package used to send the messages is the AWS SDK for PHP:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

Official Documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Sns.SnsClient.html

Some examples:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/sns-examples-sending-sms.html

This frustrated sad person has the only question I could find related to this issue:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=315153

Answer (score -1):

#### Background info

As mentioned in the SNS docs, each SMS message can contain up to 140 bytes, and the character quota depends on the encoding scheme. For example, an SMS message can contain:

- 160 GSM characters
- 140 ASCII characters
- 70 UCS-2 characters

GSM-7 is the standard alphabet for SMS messages, and you can view it's [character set here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#GSM_7-bit_default_alphabet_and_extension_table_of_3GPP_TS_23.038_.2F_GSM_03.38%60).

When sending an SMS, SNS automatically sends messages in the most compact encoding possible. When non GSM-7 characters are included in a message, the message must be encoded in UCS-2.

UCS-2 is a fixed-width encoding; each encoded code point (aka character) will take exactly 2 bytes. As a SMS message is transmitted in 140 octets, a message which is encoded in UCS-2 has a maximum of 70 characters: `(140*8) / (2*8) = 70`

As an example, imagine a message with 152 GSM-7-compatible characters. If you add a single additional Unicode (non-GSM) character, instead of being sent as a single message, it will now be segmented and charged as three messages when encoded in UCS-2.

#### Issue

I am not fully sure why, but it appears your messages are not automatically being encoded as UCS-2.

#### Solution

If you are okay with the trade off of encoding as UCS-2 (fewer available characters per message segment), you can include a non-GSM character to force/ensure that the message is encoded as UCS-2.

As an example, you could prepend the message with a Unicode [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) character (U+200B).

Doing so in your code example could look like this:

```php
$message = $request->input('message');
$message = "\u{200B}" . $message;
```

Comment: Sorry, your suggestion doesn't work. Have tried this your self? I've come to believe that AWS does not support sending accents, some characters like ñ are sent just right... The same happens when you send the SMS messages right from the AWS Console.